# Spring Cloud Gateway OAuth2 Resource Server Backend Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Boot Backend designed as Microservice Rest Backend. I User 2 Simple Modules that publish Rest interfaces with spring-data-rest.
This Modules are reachable over spring Cloud Gateway (with Eureka service discovery)
The Frontend is React.
Now I want to secure the Backend part.
In the Gateway pom I added:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.14</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
....

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

then I edited the gatewayserver.yml

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resourceserver:
      jwt:
        jwk-set-uri: http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/iaamrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

and add this to the applikation class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class ApiGatewayserverServerApplication {

}
```

The Gateway Server is started with profile `gateway-as-resource-server`

After that I tested with insomnia, without bearer token I get an 401 Unauthorized and with bearer I get 200 OK and data.

Now I have 2 Questions

1. how to configure authorization maybe `hasAuthority("SCOPE_default-user-scope")` to check that a scope is present or do other authorization checks
2. what if one backend service calls an other backend service, do I have to forwarde the bearer token manual (maybe with filter) or is there an other possibility?

I've tryed to find out more in the spring cloud docu [Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/#httpheadersfilters)
and with google without result.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you are looking for is [Spring Security one](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/index.html): From the security point of view, `spring-cloud-gateway` configured as a resource server is just an ordinary (reactive) resource server.

#### Access Control On The Gateway

As you are writing access control on the gateway, you can't use method security (`@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority("SCOPE_default-user-scope")")` and alike) and will have to implement those rules when configuring the security filter-chain.

Be aware that if you provide a security filter-chain, it will replace the auto-configured one. As a consequence, it must be a complete resource server security filter-chain (providing just the `authorizeExchange` statements won't be enough). Sample of such a security conf in [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/reactive-resource-server) I wrote.

Other limitations of writing access control rules on the gateway are

- you can hardly unit-test those rules
- rules involving the resource itself (like "has SUPERUSER role or is the author of accessed resource") will look unnatural and introduce tight coupling to the underlying resource servers.

#### Inter-Service Calls

Two scenarios:

- the request is issued on behalf of the "user" who originated the current request, in which case the sub-request should be authorized with the Bearer token contained in the Authentication (itself retrieved from the security context)
- the request is issued by the micro-service in its own name (without the context of a user), then client credentials should be used to get a new access token

There are filters for `WebClient` to retrieve the access token from the security context and set the authorization header for you: [`ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/reactive/function/client/ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.html) and [`ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/reactive/function/client/ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.html)

#### Opinion

I personally never configure the gateway as resource server:

- I like resource servers to be responsible for the resources it manages (access control included)
- I like method security: it sticks access control rules to resources end-points (I find it much more readable and easy to understand all rules that apply to a specific URI for a specific HTTP verb)
- I like to unit test access control rules (see this [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control) I wrote)
- I like end-to-end security: if security is implemented on the gateway instead of the services, you'll have to make very sure that it is impossible to send a request to a micro-service without going through that gateway

Comment: Thanks for supporting me and thanks for the tutorials and the links.
As I understand it’s a better idea to secure each service separately. So I remove the security on the gateway.
I have the CORS config on the gateway, can I leave it like that?

As I use Spring data Rest I have to find out how to use method security or any other possibility.
At the moment I have only inter service calls issued by a user so I use the predefined filters.

Unfortunately I won't be able to test it until next week but I will report the solution.

Answer (score 0):

After the answer form ch4mp I have removed the configuration in the gateway and added the following in the service:

added this to the propertis file `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/iaamrealm`

then I created this security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter) throws Exception {
    http.oauth2ResourceServer()
      .jwt()
      .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwt -> new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt)));
    http.sessionManagement()
      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
      .and()
      .csrf()
      .disable();
    http.exceptionHandling()
      .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
      });

    //authorizeHttpRequests()
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .requestMatchers(new  AntPathRequestMatcher("/v1/api/**"))
      .hasRole("myrole") //ROLE_myrole must be added
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated();
    return http.build();
  }

  static interface AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {
  }

  @Bean
  AuthoritiesConverter realmRoles2AuthoritiesConverter() {
    return (Jwt jwt) -> {
      final var realmRoles = Optional.of(jwt.getClaimAsMap("realm_access")).orElse(Map.of());
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      final var roles = (List<String>) realmRoles.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());
      return roles.stream()
        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
        .map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
    };
  }
}
```

It took a time to figure out that the `AntPathRequestMatcher("/v1/api/**")` should not include the service name. My fist version looks like this

```
AntPathRequestMatcher("/knowledge/v1/api/**")
```

and this won't work. (the role was ignored)
HTH