# Keycloak + SPA as client (Vue) + Spring Cloud Gateway as resource server + Spring Boot Microservices

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, oauth, keycloak

I want my project to work like this:

[image]

Everything fine except for Vue(axios) returns 401 error when I request some data from microservice through gateway.

Authorization token with 'Bearer' is set for each axios request, with exacly same token I can get data using Postman. Also its work if I move

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and

```
security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8900/realms/SomeRealm
```

from Spring gateway to microservice.

But I want only gateway to approve token and microservice should not know anything about it or keycloak.

Vue 2, Spring boot 2.17, Java 11, Keycloak 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I did it. The problem was with a preflight OPTIONS header, which didn't include token. Solved with SecurityWebFilterChain:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll() // Allow OPTIONS requests without authentication
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();
    return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise to configure the Gateway as client, not as resource server, for two reasons:

- SPAs make unsafe clients. According to [latest recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), you should be using only confidential clients (SPAs and mobile apps are public clients).
- resources access control is much better implemented on the services serving this resources (avoids tight coupling between gateway and REST APIs, and makes it possible to unit test access control). I detailed why, to me, this is an anti-pattern in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75952717/619830).

A good alternative is configuring the gateway as OAuth2 client (with `oauth2Login`) and the `TokenRelay` filter as I do in [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff). This is frequently referred to as the BFF pattern and it is quite trendy because, in the end, it is much safer to authorize requests from user devices using secure http-only sessions cookies (with CSRF protection), keeping OAuth2 tokens safe on servers we can trust.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and probably follow it. But still can you explain why it doesn't work my way with Vue ? I thing Angular have same problem. Did you ever try to make it work my way ?

Comment: I can't tell why you face this issue because you provide no logs or error message. I did use "public" clients with [certified OpenID client libs](https://openid.net/certified-open-id-developer-tools/) until "public" clients usage was discouraged (see link in my answer). I never used insecure REST services behind a gateway configured as a resource server because [this is an anti-pattern to me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75952717/619830).